# JUnit Local Test - Android Context 'No instrumentation registered!'

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, junit4, android-testing

## Expected

Access the Android **Context** within a **local JUnit** test as outlined in the Android Documentation [Build local unit tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html) example [*MyLocalUnitTestClass*](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#include-framework-dependencies).

## Observed

#### Runtime Error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.

## Implementation

The attempted implementation may also be found at the Coinverse Open App GitHub project under the [*test/poc* branch](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse/tree/test/poc).

**Directory** - *app > src > test > java*

*ExampleUnitTest.kt*

```
package app.coinverse

import android.content.Context
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Test

class ExampleUnitTest {

    val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()

    @Test
    fun addition_isCorrect() {
        FirebaseHelper.initialize(context)
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2)
    }
}
```

*build.gradle (Module: app)*

The library dependencies are based both off of the [Set up your testing environment](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#setup) documentation and the [Android Testing Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) [*build.gradle*](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-testing/blob/codelab2019/app/build.gradle) configuration. The only test type implemented is the *Local Unit* test. However, included are dependencies for *Android Unit* and *Instrumented* tests just in case.

Below is the code / libraries related to testing.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    sourceSets {
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }

    // Gradle automatically adds 'android.test.runner' as a dependency.
    useLibrary 'android.test.runner'
    useLibrary 'android.test.base'
    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'

    testOptions {
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Testing

    // Local Unit
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.19.0'
    testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3"
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.2.1"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.2.1"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3"
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0'
    testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.44'

    // Android Unit
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.19.0'
    androidTestImplementation "com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.12.1"
    androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.2.1"

    // AndroidX - JVM
    testImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:1.2.0"
    testImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.1"
    testImplementation "androidx.test:rules:1.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.0-alpha02"
    implementation "androidx.test:core:1.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0-alpha02"

    // Instrumented testing
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:1.2.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:1.2.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.2.0"
    androidTestImplementation "org.robolectric:annotations:4.3"
    implementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.2.0"

    // Resolve conflicts between main and test APK:
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

## Attempted Solutions

- *File > Invalidate Caches and Restart...*
- Initiate the Context before running the test resulting in the same runtime error.

*ExampleUnitTest.kt*

```
@Before
fun setup() {
    val context = getApplicationContext<Context>()
}
```

- Move the *ExampleUnitTest.kt* class into a *sharedTest* directory as outlined in the [*Running your first test*](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#4) section of the Testing Codelab.

**Directory** - *app > src > sharedTest > java*

*build.gradle (Module: app)*

```
android {
        sourceSets {
            String sharedTestDir = 'src/sharedTest/java'
            test {
                java.srcDir sharedTestDir
            }
            androidTest {
                java.srcDir sharedTestDir
            }
        }
}
```

## Addendum

#### Full Error Message

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.
>
> at androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.java:45)
>
> at androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(ApplicationProvider.java:41)
>
> at app.coinverse.ExampleUnitTest.setup(ExampleUnitTest.kt:29)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>
> at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>
> at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>
> at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>
> at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>
> at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>
> at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>
> at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

**Refactor `AndroidViewModel` implementation to `ViewModel` as outlined in [Jose Alcérreca](https://medium.com/@JoseAlcerreca)'s post [Locale changes and the AndroidViewModel antipattern](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/locale-changes-and-the-androidviewmodel-antipattern-84eb677660d9#ece9)**

This refactor will remove the need to create Application Context.

In addition to the ViewModel refactor, pass components into the ViewModel as an argument to separate dependencies. A [Dependency Injection](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1H4eCai4HROxWGxFi2LXcgaAgTdrW4hkldHHrFoRV8eI/edit?rm=minimal) library may be used in the new ViewModel in order to create required components (ie — Repository, Database, Analytics, and etc.) and de-couple them from the ViewModel as well.